# Can I get a value localized by javascript in blade template?

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, localized

In html, I can get a value localized by below code:

```
{{Lang::get('frontend/error_message.EMAIL_BLANK')}}
```

I want to use `javascript` to check valid input data, and get value from localized, but it not working with below code:

```
error = <?php echo \Lang::get('frontend/error_message.EMAIL_BLANK');?>
error = <?php echo Lang::get('frontend/error_message.EMAIL_BLANK');?>
error = {{Lang::get('frontend/error_message.EMAIL_BLANK')}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably just need to put in some `"`

```
error = "<?php echo \Lang::get('frontend/error_message.EMAIL_BLANK');?>"
error = "<?php echo Lang::get('frontend/error_message.EMAIL_BLANK');?>"
error = "{{Lang::get('frontend/error_message.EMAIL_BLANK')}}"
```